# Drop drown from numbers 1-100 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

Need a drop down for numbers 1-10 by using javascript and default value to 10, I shouldn't use jQuery in our application. Can someone help me to do this.

Comment: sure.  have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <form:select path="priority" id="priority" class="col-sm-2" cssClass="form-control">                       
 </form:select>
```

Javascript function:

```
 var select = '';
            for (i=1;i<=10;i++){
                select += '<option val=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>';
            }
            $('#priority').html(select);
```